# Python ZipFile path separators

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

If I am unzipping a Zip file with the Python ZipFile library, where the file was created on Windows, but my code is running on Unix-like, will the path separators always be Unix-style?

Comment: Seems like it has to be since it's not stored as a string. I sure hope so :)

Comment: You would hope so! But when you're dealing with computers, hope has nothing to do with anything...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Internally, ZipFile stores forward slashes as required by the [zip file specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

Externally, they get translated using [os.sep](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.sep) so it will match what is normally expected on a given platform.

Code references:

- http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/zipfile.py#l295
- http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/zipfile.py#l1046

Comment: Thank you! I assumed this was true but it's good to have evidence.

Comment: Note that this conversion is only applied when creating an entry in the ZIP archive. When accessing existing members (e.g. with `zip_file.read('dir/file.txt')`) slashes have to be always used.

Comment: +1 for the link to the zip file spec. Thanks!!! Here's the relevant section:
4.4.17 file name: (Variable)

       4.4.17.1 The name of the file, with optional relative path.
       The path stored MUST not contain a drive or
       device letter, or a leading slash.  All slashes
       MUST be forward slashes '/' as opposed to
       backwards slashes '\' for compatibility with Amiga
       and UNIX file systems etc.  If input came from standard
       input, there is no file name field.